# Raytracing in JavafX (2D) - running through single pixels viable?

Tags: java, javafx, raytracing

Good day fellow programmers,

I'm writing a graphical application in JavaFX that requires me to use simple 2D raytracing to see if there is an object somewhere in between start and end of the line I use for raytracing.

I have implemented a method that works, but I'm not sure whether it's good programming or not, since it runs through (more or less) every single pixel on the way to the end and checks whether there is an object or not.

```
public boolean hasLineOfSight()
{
    boolean sight = true;

    List<Block> blocks = level.getBlocks();
    for (Block b : blocks)
    {
        if (b instanceof SolidBlock)
        {
            double length = Utility.getLengthOfLine(lineOfSight);
            double dir = Math.atan2(lineOfSight.getEndY() - lineOfSight.getStartY(), lineOfSight.getEndX() - lineOfSight.getStartX());
            System.out.println(length);

            // DURCHLÄUFT DIE GESAMTE LINIE UND PRÜFT JEDEN ZWEITEN PUNKT
            // AUF EINEN SOLIDEN BLOCK
            for (int i = 0; i <= length / 2; i++)
            {
                if (level.getSolidBlock((int) (lineOfSight.getStartX() + 2 * i * Math.cos(dir)), (int) (lineOfSight.getStartY() + 2 * i * Math.sin(dir))) != level.nullBlock)
                {
                    sight = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sight;
}
```

The method above shall only test SolidBlocks.
The line lineOfSight is the line between an Enemy object and the Player object and is always correctly updated.
double dir is the angle of the line, so that I can iterate based on the angle to check a lot of coordinates.
Basically, what the for-loop does is check every ~2nd pixel (I could also run through every pixel, which would be more precise, but would cost more performance).

So far, this code works, but since my application requires me to use raytracing when I've never used raytracing ever (I also didn't find a lot of concrete info on the subject), I wanted to ask if my understanding of the subject is correct and if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.